# ImportError: Failed to import test module

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

Trying to run some test and I run into this error, im using Python 2.7.3 and Django 1.5.

```
python -m unittest discover
E
======================================================================
ERROR: mapvis.test_select_nodes_from_rectangle (unittest.loader.ModuleImportFailure)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError: Failed to import test module: mapvis.test_select_nodes_from_rectangle
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/loader.py", line 252, in _find_tests
    module = self._get_module_from_name(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/loader.py", line 230, in _get_module_from_name
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/pierre/maps3/lmap/mapvis/test_select_nodes_from_rectangle.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django.core.context_processors import csrf
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/context_processors.py", line 12, in <module>
    from django.middleware.csrf import get_token
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/middleware/csrf.py", line 16, in <module>
    from django.utils.cache import patch_vary_headers
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/cache.py", line 26, in <module>
    from django.core.cache import get_cache
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/cache/__init__.py", line 70, in <module>
    if DEFAULT_CACHE_ALIAS not in settings.CACHES:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 52, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 45, in _setup
    % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting CACHES, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

test_select_nodes_from_rectangle.py

```
from django.core.context_processors import csrf
....
....
import random
import unittest

....
....
....

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: Thanks for the question. It solved me another issue: I got "ModuleImportFailure: instead of test case (might be due to https://bugs.python.org/issue19746) running `python -m unittest discover` helped to find out the error (indentation...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested in the error message set the environment variable to let Django know which file holds the project settings:

```
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=settings.module python -m unittest discover
```

Or launch the tests like this:

```
./manage.py test
```

Comment: I have my settings file in the same folder as my unittest, how do i set it up to use it? Tried using you example but didnt work, got the following error ImportError: Could not import settings 'settings.module' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named module

Comment: if your settings file is called `settings.py` and your application is called `mapvis`, then try: `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mapvis.settings python -m unittest discover`. Read about settings module [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/#envvar-DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE)

Comment: If you have `manage.py` in the same directory, try: `python manage.py test`